# how to get filepath after copy?

Tags: java, android

I'm using this function that I got from another question for copy an image:

```
public static boolean copyFile(String from, String to) {
    try {
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        if (sd.canWrite()) {
            int end = from.toString().lastIndexOf("/");
            String str1 = from.toString().substring(0, end);
            String str2 = from.toString().substring(end+1, from.length());
            File source = new File(str1, str2);
            File destination= new File(to, str2);
            if (source.exists()) {
                FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(source).getChannel();
                FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(destination).getChannel();
                dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                src.close();
                dst.close();
            }
        }
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and I'm using that in this way:

```
               String filePath = Helper.pathgal(act, data.getData());
               File mydir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Albummaker/Pics/");

               if (!mydir.exists()) {
                   mydir.mkdirs();
               } else {
                   Log.d("error", "dir. already exists");
               }

               String dest = mydir.getAbsolutePath();
               copyFile(filePath, dest);

               // now I want to use destination file path for using in a bitmap
               bmp = Helper.decodeFile(dest, act);

               // now I'm loading that bitmap in an imageview
               Helper.showpic(act, id1, bmp);
```

But It's not showing in ImageView (If I use original file path it's working though). the copy function is working and the image file exist in final filepath but I think I should add file name some how to "mydir" file path for using in bitmap.

Comment: you have not specified filename in any of the above code.   String dest = mydir.getAbsolutePath()+"myfile.png"; something like this is required

Comment: @IllegalArgument my question is exactly this. how to get this "file name"? (It's not same file every time and it changes.)

Comment: my answer is exactly that your file name in above comment is "myfile.png" so you know that it is "myfile.png" before accesing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the copy function is working and the image file exist in final filepath but I think I should add file name some how to "mydir" file path for using in bitmap.

Yes, your dest variable doesn't contain your image file. It is just a folder "../Albummaker/Pics/"

You show return the destination file in the copyFile method:

```
public static File copyFile(String from, String to) {
try {
    File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    if (sd.canWrite()) {
        int end = from.toString().lastIndexOf("/");
        String str1 = from.toString().substring(0, end);
        String str2 = from.toString().substring(end+1, from.length());
        File source = new File(str1, str2);
        File destination= new File(to, str2);
        if (source.exists()) {
            FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(source).getChannel();
            FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(destination).getChannel();
            dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
            src.close();
            dst.close();
        }
    }
    return destination;
} catch (Exception e) {
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: and then? how can I get file name from destination? (Your returnings also are not in right position).

Comment: I think you can get the path via   File desFile = copyFile(filePath, dest);
Helper.decodeFile(desFile.getAbsolutePath(), act);

Comment: Thanks for simple answer :)